# Comparing NAMESPACE files between different R package versions

Tags: r, r-pacs

Regularly we are using the `parseNamespaceFile("PACKAGE", package.lib = .libPaths())` or `getNamespaceImports("PACKAGE")`/`getNamespaceExports("PACKAGE")` functions to retrieve a NAMESPACE file metadata for any local package. Unfortunately it is not easy to compare NAMESPACE files between different package versions. Mostly we want to get diff of imports and exports between different package versions.
How to achieve such objective.

- self-promotion of my new CRAN package https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=pacs

Answer (score 0):

My own solution for such problem is offered in `pacs` CRAN package.
`pacs::pac_compare_namespace` could be used to compare NAMESPACE file fields between different package versions.
`pacs::pac_namespace` is offered to enable download of NAMESPACE file for any package version or at a specific Date.
Functions are supported for R CRAN packages.

Comparing a package NAMESPACE fields between different versions.

```r
head(pacs::pac_compare_namespace("dplyr", "0.8.1", "1.0.0"), 1)
#> $imports
#> $imports$removed
#>  [1] "Rcpp"              "Rcpp.plugin.maker" "cppFunction"      
#>  [4] "assertthat"        "on_failure<-"      "assert_that"      
#>  [7] "is.flag"           "pkgconfig"         "get_config"       
#> [10] ":="                ".data"             "as_label"         
#> [13] "as_name"           "dots_n"            "enquo"            
#> [16] "enquos"            "expr"              "sym"              
#> [19] "syms"             
#> 
#> $imports$added
#>  [1] "vctrs"         "generics"      "intersect"     "setdiff"      
#>  [5] "setequal"      "union"         "glue_collapse" "glue_data"    
#>  [9] "lifecycle"     "deprecated"    "view"          "all_of"       
#> [13] "any_of"
```

Raw NAMESPACE files for a version or at Date.

```r
pacs::pac_namespace("dplyr", "0.8.1")

pacs::pac_namespace("dplyr", at = as.Date("2018-01-01"))
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>